# Nginx installation errors in debian 8.3

Tags: nginx, debian

```
Setting up nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u1) | nginx-light (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u1); however:
 Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
 Package nginx-light is not installed.
 Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u1.1~); however:
 Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
 Package nginx-light is not installed.
 Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Above is the error that is given to me when running sudo apt-get install nginx. I tried removing apache and nginx both and reinstalling but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I DO NOT have Apache, and nothing else was blocking my port 80.
I could NOT install nginx with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

nor with

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-common nginx-full
```

After one week I stumbled over this little blog: https://etc.banana.fish/?p=75

In this blog, the solution is:

1. Install nginx-common: `sudo apt-get install nginx-common`
2. Remove `listen [::]:80 default_server;` from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** (I made this using the root-user)
3. Just to be sure, I did reboot my server.
4. Just to be sure twice, I did `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
5. Now I finally called `sudo apt-get install nginx-full` and it worked!

Afterwords I could see the Titlescreen of nginx, when I typed in the IP of my remote server!

Comment: Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't post the output of `systemctl status nginx.service` so this might not be right, but I had this issue because I had an old install of nginx I'd forgotten about.

So, I purged nginx and reinstalled:

```
    apt-get purge nginx-full nginx-common
    apt-get install nginx-full
```

Then I received another error, got the details: `systemctl status nginx.service`

In my case

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

So I have another web server listening on port 80.

To fix, I edited the default nginx site `nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and removed listen on port 80.

I only needed SSL, so:

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        //rest of config....
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Helped for me:

```
service apache2 stop
apt-get remove apache2*
apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I had just to run the first line to solve the issue for info

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problems while installing nginx on ubuntu16 Amazon EC2 instance and the cause seems to be that I fiddled with the inbound ports under my security group settings
ideally they should be:
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
and

HTTP
TCP
80
::/0

I had removed one of them for some reason by mistake it appears, when I fixed that everything got sorted

Comment: I managed to get the problem sorted by following ElectRocnic's answer which is similar to yours. Thank you for the support :)